# How do you calculate the leakage current for the I2C interface in the active and sleep states?

Tags: digital-logic, i2c, hardware, leakage-current

How do you calculate the leakage current and power loss for the I2C interface in the active and sleep states? Consider that the I2C operates at the maximum data rate of 1 MHz (Fast mode plus), with a 2.2 kΩ pull-up resistor, a pull-up voltage of 1.8 V, and a single slave device.

Additionally, does the leakage current vary based on the I2C modes/data rates - Standard mode, Fast mode, Fast mode plus?

Furthermore, does the leakage current vary based on read and write operations?

Your comprehensive response would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: From the datasheet?

Comment: Can you please share the example calculation here?

Comment: Also, how to calculate the leakage current during idle state?

Comment: Can you please share a link to the datasheet?

Comment: You are mixing leakage current with operating current. The leakage will read on data sheet, the oprating current will depend on your resistor. It is impossible to answer anything without knowing which chips you use. The optimum case will be zero leakage, and max 1.64mA when I2C wires are stuck low for some reason. If you need better approximations, you need to give better description.